# Issue with part of menu bar disappearing on reseize

Tags: html, css, resize, window-resize

I have a website I'm designing and I ran across a problem with resizing.

Here is my website when maximized in Chromium 28.0:
[image: Website Screenshot in Chromium] and you can see the grey menu bar reaches all the way across.

However, when I go to resize the window:
[image: Website Screenshot in Chromium - Resized]

The code for that div (#header) is:

```
 #header {
    background-color: #dcdcdc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    padding: 27px 0;
}
```

so there is no set width.

What's going on?

**EDIT: 11/1/2013**
Here's my HTML for the header:

```
<div id="header">
        <div>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html">Thumbnails</a>
            </div>
            <ul id="navigation">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="features.html">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="news.html">News</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**EDIT: 11/1/2013** Firefox Screenshot:

I added a screenshot from Firefox and the problem affects the footer as well (happens in Chromium as well)

[image: Firefox Screenshot (Firefox 25.0)]

Comment: can you provide your markup + css?

Comment: its working fine. just width size only changes when u resize the window. but i didn't see color issues here..??

Comment: @Indians Yes, that's my problem. The size of the menu bar shrinks, so it becomes white.

Comment: @onestepcreative I updated my post with the HTML.

Comment: We need to see the whole CSS...there is clearly something else going on. A JSFiddle would reduced case would help us help you.

Comment: @Paulie_D I will do this, but my battery is about to die and I left my charging cord at a friends house. Will do this as soon as I can.

Comment: @Paulie_D Here it is, sorry about the late response. http://jsfiddle.net/RPiAwesomeness/rBAnK/

Comment: @onestepcreative I just created a JSFiddle for the problem page: http://jsfiddle.net/RPiAwesomeness/rBAnK/

Comment: @Paulie_D I uploaded the JSFiddle and I still need help and have yet to fix my problem.

Comment: are you trying to have this header be responsive, or should it have a set minimum width?

Comment: @onestepcreative I am attempting to make it so that no matter what when the browser gets resized the grey stays from edge to edge

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness I provided an answer below that should work. Does it not?

Comment: @onestepcreative Sorry. I posted that and then realized you had answered it already. My bad :D

Answer (score 1):

After simplifying your html + css, I came up with a solution that appears to work as intended. I believe the problem was the way you had setup the padding + margin.

The HTML:

```
<div class="page-container">

    <header class="top-bar">
        <div class="inner">

            <h2 class="logo">Logo</h2>

            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="main-content"></section>

    <footer class="bottom-bar">
        <div class="inner">

            <span class="copyright">Copyright info here.</span>

            <span class="contact">Contact info here.</span>

        </div>
    </footer>

</div>

</body>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.page-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}



/* ===============================================
/* ====== HEADER + NAVIGATION STYLES
/* ============================================ */

.top-bar {
    background: #EEE;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner {
    background: #DDD;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 920px;
}

.logo {
    background: #CCC;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 35px 0;
    width: 120px;
}

.main-nav {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 35px 0;
}

.main-nav li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
}

.main-nav li a {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav li.active a,
.main-nav li a:hover {
    color: #F99600;
}



/* ===============================================
/* ====== MAIN CONTENT PLACEHOLDER STYLES
/* ============================================ */

.main-content {
    background: #F6F6F6;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 920px;
}



/* ===============================================
/* ====== FOOTER ELEMENT STYLES
/* ============================================ */

.bottom-bar {
    background: #EEE;
    height: 100px;
}

.bottom-bar .copyright,
.bottom-bar .contact {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 35px;
}

.copyright { float: left; }
.contact { float: right; }
```

You can check out the working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/onestepcreative/X8QbD/

Comment: This does solve the problem but it also changes the design slightly. Is there any way I can fix the problem without severely changing the design?